# Python Numpy Array Fill in the blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Fill in section A to complete code that will cause the following output:

```
import numpy as np
j = np.random.random([2,2])
print (j)
print (_A_)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.1624438 , 0.14157016],
[ 0.07818402, 0.85854546]]
[[ 1. , 1. ],
[ 0.48129886, 6.06445229]])
```

I tried using np.corrcoef, it gives me all values as 1. Can you please help me?

Comment: Try to explain your question. Make what you are trying to achieve clear, instead of copy pasting random values. Also explain your own attempt at doing it, do not just throw the name of the function you tried using. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help at framing a question.

Comment: This question does not need the `python-3.x` tag. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example I am taking exact same j to make you understand.

```
j=np.array([[ 0.1624438 , 0.14157016],
            [ 0.07818402, 0.85854546]])

print(j)

array([[0.1624438 , 0.14157016],
       [0.07818402, 0.85854546]])

A = j/j[0]
print(A)

array([[1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.48129889, 6.06445214]])
```

So, **A** will be `j/j[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel I should've tried a bit harder.